# How to calculate $\begin{cases}y''+4y = \cos{2t}+t^2 \\y(0) = 1;y'(0) = 0\end{cases}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this Cauchy Problem

$$\begin{cases}y''+4y = \cos{2t}+t^2 \\y(0) = 1;y'(0) = 0\end{cases}$$

So far, i made the following steps:

1. **Solutions of the characteristic equation**

   $$\lambda^2+4\lambda = 0$$ $$\lambda_{1} = 0 , \lambda_{2} = -4$$
   $$Y_{om}(t) = a_1\cos{2t}+a_2\sin{2t}$$
2. **Looking for the particular solution and then $Y_{gen}(t) = Y_{om}(t)+Y_p(t)$**

   $$Y_1p(t) = a\cos{2t}+b\sin{2t}$$ $$Y_2p(t) = ct^2+dt+e$$
   $$Y_p(t) = a\cos{2t}+b\sin{2t}+ct^2+dt+e$$

Now i should calculate the first derivative and the second derivative of the particular solution and then replace in the equation in order to find the values ​​of the coefficients $$a,b,c,d,e$$

I tried many attempts but i can't get the result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an issue with:

$$\lambda^2+4\lambda = 0$$

It should be:

$$\lambda^2+4 = 0$$

Comment: A bad distraction mistake. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems - one is in finding $Y_{om}$ and the other is in finding $Y_p$. Your characteristic polynomial should be $\lambda^2 + 4 = 0$ giving solutions of $\lambda = \pm 2i$, which does result in the $Y_{om}$ you have found.

The other problem you are having is in your $Y_1p(t)$. When doing the method of undetermined coefficients to solve a differential equation, you need the particular solution to be independent of the general solution you have already found. Since $Y_1p(t)$ is the same as $Y_{om}(t)$, you get $0$ from plugging $Y_1p(t)$ back into the differential equation. You need to take your initial guess and multiply through by $t$ to make it independent of $Y_{om}$. So $Y_1p(t) = at\cos2t + bt\sin 2t$.

Comment: nice answer @john